# If Thomson Reuters says it indexes a journal but it's not mentioned on the journal's web site, who should I trust?

Tags: journals, indexing

On the Thomson Reuters Master Journal list is stated that the given journal is indexed in Science Citation Index and Current Contents. However, on the official journal's web page, there is no such information.

In addition, the journal has Impact Factor. I also checked on the Thomson Journal Citation Report to be sure.

Who should I trust in this case?

Comment: You should trust the results of a search for the journal in Science Citation Index.  If the search is successful, then it's indexed; if your search is unsuccessful, then it isn't.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it a subscription-based journal?

Answer (score 1):

Trust Thomson Reuters, of course. It has all its JCR impact factors up to date.

Beware that there are many journals that print impact factors on their own site with their own definitions making a facade impression to prospective readers and authors. Do not confuse them with JCR impact factors.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. But this is Elsevier journal and on the journal's webpage, under the IF, there is copyright mark of Thompson Reuters. So I guess I could be pretty confident that this is the real IF.

Comment: Yes @Navi, but there is always the *up-to-date* aspect of Reuters.